# Multiple buttons in a popup, trying to stay organized

Tags: android, android-fragments, popup, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I'm implementing a popup in fragment Tab3Fragment and would like to keep the popup code in,

```
 public void showPopup(View anchorView){
 }
```

and  minimized elsewhere in the Tab3Fragment as much as possible to keep things tidy.

Currently showPopup looks something like this,

```
public void showPopup(View anchorView) {    
    Button btnDismiss, btnFirstRecord, btnPreviousRecord, btnNextRecord, btnLastRecord;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemServi (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);    
    TextView tv = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setText("Blah, blah, blah");

    btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.btnDismissxml);
    btnFirstRecord = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.btnFirstRecordxml);
    btnPreviousRecord = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.btnPreviousRecordxml);
    btnNextRecord = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.btnNextRecordxml);
    btnLastRecord = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.btnLastRecordxml);

    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    int location[] = new int[2];
    anchorView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(anchorView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }   
}
```

**QUESTION:** Is there any way to implement an onClick method case-switch statement inside of showPopup that would handle this? Perhaps something like,

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {       
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnFirstRecordxml:
        //firstRecord(v);
        break;
    case R.id.btnPreviousRecordxml:
        //previousRecord(v);
        break;
    case R.id.btnNextRecordxml:
        //nextRecord(v);
        break;
    case R.id.btnLastRecordxml:
        //lastRecord(v);
        break;
    case R.id.btnDismissxml:
        //closePopup(v);
        break;  
    }}
```

**Other solutions** such as putting onClick in popup_layout.xml thusly,

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFirstRecordxml"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pszFirstRecordButton" 
    android:onClick="Tab3Fragment.firstRecord"/>
```

to handle button clicks would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance...

**Update, 23 Nov 2014.** 
Here is a solution that does work for more than one button's code in showPopup(). I'll have several buttons in the popup....

```
private void showPopup(){
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);
    Button btnDismiss=(Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.btnDismissxml);
    Button btnSaveRecord=(Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.btnSaveRecordxml);
    final PopupWindow popupWindow=new PopupWindow(popupView,480,500,true);
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 40);                                   
//first button
    btnSaveRecord.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            saveRecord();
        }
    });
 //second button
    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Any way to insert a case-switch structure to allow other button code in showPopup()? This would avoid creating separate onClickListener-onClicks for each button as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the xml like this, use `android:onClick="ClickEvent"` this formet in all the button

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btnFirstRecordxml"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/pszFirstRecordButton" 
android:onClick="ClickEvent"/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/btnPreviousRecordxml"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/pszPreviousRecordButton" 
android:onClick="ClickEvent"/>
```

use the click funcationality like this,

```
public void clickEvent(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.btnFirstRecordxml:
    //firstRecord(v);
    break;
case R.id.btnPreviousRecordxml:
    //previousRecord(v);
    break;
case R.id.btnNextRecordxml:
    //nextRecord(v);
    break;
case R.id.btnLastRecordxml:
    //lastRecord(v);
    break;
case R.id.btnDismissxml:
    //closePopup(v);
    break;  
}
}
```

Or try this,

`btn.setOnClickListener(btnaction);`  set like this listener for all buttons,

```
 OnClickListener btnaction = new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
     //use the switch conditons...
   }
 };
btn1.setOnClickListener(btnaction);
btn2.setOnClickListener(btnaction);
```

Comment: Is there a way to format the clickEvent(View v) to allow the code to reside in the showPopup method? Thanks!

Comment: Previously clickEvent works fine outside of showPopup in fragment Tab3Fragment, but not inside of showPopup. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: i have added some latest code,try that code and let me know ,it's works ?

Comment: Thanks Prakash. I've updated my question w/your suggested code- however I do not think that I've implemented what you intended. Thanks again.

Comment: remove this android:onClick="Tab3Fragment.firstRecord" in all your buttons inyour xml and try it.

Comment: Thanks, but I did that earlier w/no luck. I have shown the error messages in the code above that I am getting and where they are...the messages are, "error message #1-"btnaction cannot be resolved to a variable" error message #2-"Multiple markers at this line - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement - btnaction cannot be resolved to a variable" error message #3-"Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)" Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void showPopup(View anchorView) {    
    Button btnDismiss, btnFirstRecord, btnPreviousRecord, btnNextRecord, btnLastRecord;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemServi (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);    
    TextView tv = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setText("Blah, blah, blah");

    btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.btnDismissxml);
    btnFirstRecord = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.btnFirstRecordxml);
    btnPreviousRecord = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.btnPreviousRecordxml);
    btnNextRecord = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.btnNextRecordxml);
    btnLastRecord = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.btnLastRecordxml);

btnFirstRecord.setOnClickListener(new Listener());
btnPreviousRecord.setOnClickListener(new Listener());
btnNextRecord .setOnClickListener(new Listener());
btnLastRecord .setOnClickListener(new Listener()); 

    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    int location[] = new int[2];
    anchorView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(anchorView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }   
}


Class Listener implements OnClickListener
{
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
 switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnFirstRecordxml:
        //firstRecord(v);
        break;
    case R.id.btnPreviousRecordxml:
        //previousRecord(v);
        break;
    case R.id.btnNextRecordxml:
        //nextRecord(v);
        break;
    case R.id.btnLastRecordxml:
        //lastRecord(v);
        break;
    case R.id.btnDismissxml:
        //closePopup(v);
        break;  
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit. I've already got something very similar to what you've posted. I am looking for a method to move "public void onClick(View v)" to inside of showPopup...OR possibly have onClick called in the xml file. Do you think that this might be possible? Regards.

Comment: It is posible only when you set clicklistener to individual button other wise not possible inside the showpop method

Comment: I think that I have come to the same conclusion regarding clicklisteners in showpop(). What about onClick sent from within the XML file? I cannot get the popup_layout.xml file to send an onClick button event when attempting this. Thanks for your response on this.

Comment: When you use on click in xml its works only when you use setContentView in onCreate function and popup is used as another layout so it is not possible to use the onclick method of popup layout in an activity